# Smooth rotation of QGraphicsObject

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6

```
    from PySide6.QtCore import QRect, QPoint, QRectF, Qt
    from PySide6.QtGui import QMouseEvent, QBrush, QColor, QPen, QTransform, QGuiApplication
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsObject, QGraphicsItem
    
    
    class ImageBox(QGraphicsObject):
        def __init__(self, pixmap):
            super().__init__()
            self.image = pixmap
            self.mousePressPos = None
            self.mousePressRect = None
            self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
    
            self.isMirroredHorizontally = False
            self.isMirroredVertically = False
            self.rotate_op = False
    
            self.rect = self.image.rect()
    
            self.moving = []
            self.origin = QPoint()
    
            self.setTransformOriginPoint(self.rect.center())
    
        def getPixmap(self):
            return self.image
    
        def mirrorHorizontally(self):
            rect = self.boundingRect()
            self.isMirroredHorizontally = not self.isMirroredHorizontally
            scaleX = -1 if self.isMirroredHorizontally else 1
            scaleY = -1 if self.isMirroredVertically else 1
            transform = QTransform(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, 0, 0)
            self.setTransform(transform)
            if self.isMirroredHorizontally:
                self.moveBy(rect.width(), 0)
            else:
                self.moveBy(-rect.width(), 0)
    
        def mirrorVertically(self):
            rect = self.boundingRect()
            self.isMirroredVertically = not self.isMirroredVertically
            scaleX = -1 if self.isMirroredHorizontally else 1
            scaleY = -1 if self.isMirroredVertically else 1
            transform = QTransform(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, 0, 0)
            self.setTransform(transform)
            if self.isMirroredVertically:
                self.moveBy(0, rect.height())
            else:
                self.moveBy(0, -rect.height())
    
        def corners_rect(self) -> list:
            """ Return corner rect geometry for each corner"""
            size = 10  # Розмір елементів масштабування
            size2 = self.rect.width() - 40  # Ширина контейнера
            size3 = self.rect.height() - 40  # Висота контейнера
            half_size = size / 2  # Половина розміру елементів масштабування
            return [
                QRect(self.rect.left() - half_size, self.rect.top() - half_size, size, size),  # top left
                QRect(self.rect.right() - half_size, self.rect.top() - half_size, size, size),  # top right
                QRect(self.rect.left() - half_size, self.rect.bottom() - half_size, size, size),  # bottom left
                QRect(self.rect.right() - half_size, self.rect.bottom() - half_size, size, size),  # bottom right
                QRect(self.rect.left() + 20, self.rect.top() - half_size, size2, size),
                # top edge
                QRect(self.rect.right() - half_size, self.rect.top() + 20, size, size3),
                # right edge
                QRect(self.rect.left() + 20, self.rect.bottom() - half_size, size2, size),
                # bottom edge
                QRect(self.rect.left() - half_size, self.rect.top() + 20, size, size3),
                # left edge
            ]
    
        def boundingRect(self) -> QRectF:
            """ Override boundingRect """
            return self.rect.adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10)
    
        def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
            painter.drawPixmap(self.rect, self.image)
    
            painter.drawRect(self.rect)
    
            point_list = self.corners_rect()
    
            if self.isSelected():
    
                pen = QPen(QColor("#00FFFF"))  # Set the color of the border
                pen.setWidth(3)  # Set the width of the border
                painter.setPen(pen)
                painter.drawRect(self.rect)
    
                painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor("#00FFFF")))
                painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
                for count, rect in enumerate(point_list[:4], start=0):
                    painter.drawEllipse(rect)
    
            self.update()
    
    
        def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
            """ override mouse Press Event """
            point_list = self.corners_rect()
            self.moving = [rect.contains(QPoint(event.pos().toPoint())) for rect in point_list]
            if any(self.moving):
                self.origin = self.rect.topLeft()
            else:
                super().mousePressEvent(event)
    
        def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
            """ Override mouse release event """
            self.moving = [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
            super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
    
        def rotateWithMouse(self, mouse_position):
            center = self.rect.center()
            angle = math.atan2(mouse_position.y() - center.y(), mouse_position.x() - center.x())
            angle = math.degrees(angle)
            self.setRotation(angle)
    
        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
            """ Override mouse move event """
            if any(self.moving):
                # If moving is set from mousePressEvent , change geometry
                self.prepareGeometryChange()
    
                pos = event.pos().toPoint()
    
                self.rotate_op = False
    
                if QGuiApplication.keyboardModifiers() == Qt.ShiftModifier:
                    self.rotate_op = True
                    self.rotateWithMouse(event.pos())
    
                if self.rotate_op == False:
                    if self.moving[0] or self.moving[2]:  # top left or bottom left
                        self.rect.setLeft(pos.x())
                    if self.moving[0] or self.moving[1]:  # top left or top right
                        self.rect.setTop(pos.y())
                    if self.moving[1] or self.moving[3]:  # top right or bottom right
                        self.rect.setRight(pos.x())
                    if self.moving[2] or self.moving[3]:  # bottom left or bottom right
                        self.rect.setBottom(pos.y())
    
                    if self.moving[4]:  # top edge
                        self.rect.setTop(pos.y())
                    if self.moving[6]:  # bottom edge
                        self.rect.setBottom(pos.x())
                        self.rect.setBottom(pos.y())
                    if self.moving[5]:  # right edge
                        self.rect.setRight(pos.x())
                    if self.moving[7]:  # left edge
                        self.rect.setLeft(pos.x())
    
                self.rect = self.rect.normalized()
                self.update()
                return
            else:
                super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
```

I have a main class QGraphicsView into which I add images as ImageBox(QGraphicsObject) objects. The ImageBox has several QRect points that are used to resize the ImageBox. I added rotation to the mouseMoveEvent method when the "Shift" button is pressed, but as a result, when moving the cursor, QGraphicsObject constantly trembles or returns the rotation to the position that was a few milliseconds ago, in a word - unstable. I want to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not considering two important aspects:

1. the event mouse position is always in local coordinates (including transformations), while `setRotation()` is based on the parent: the angle you're getting does not consider the current rotation, so you should always call `setRotation()` considering the *current* `rotation()` too.
2. you must consider the angle between the center of the rectangle and the control point, and subtract it from the angle of the new mouse position;

```py
    def rotateWithMouse(self, mouse_position):
        center = self.rect.center()
        point = self.corners_rect()[self.moving.index(True)]
        pointAngle = math.degrees(math.atan2(
            point.y() - center.y(), point.x() - center.x()))
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(
            mouse_position.y() - center.y(), mouse_position.x() - center.x()))
        self.setRotation(self.rotation() + (angle - pointAngle))
```

Also note that you need to be careful about the following:

- whenever you change the rectangle geometry, you should always update the `transformOriginPoint` to the *new* center;
- `boundingRect()` should always return a QRectF, but you're returning the `QImage.rect()` which is a basic (integer based) QRect; change that to `QRectF(self.rect.adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10))`;
- you should call `prepareGeometryChange()` only when changing the bounding rect of the item, not when applying transformations (like the rotation);
- you shall **never** call `update` within `paint()`, because it will cause indirect recursion (scheduling unnecessary repaints);